# Calling UITableView datasource methods beforehand when the view is not present

Tags: ios, objective-c, multithreading, uitableview, datasource

I have dropped my code into a situation where I need to call UITableView data source methods written in some UIViewController class before a particular view is presented so that the cells get prepopulated and I can set a BOOL that the data in the not present viewController class is valid or not. I may explain it in more detail if required, but I wanted to know if its possible to do that. If yes, then how to do it? ..  as a particular set of my code written after [tableView reloadData] is dependent on running the dataSource methods of UITableView. Please throw some light on this, if needs to be handled in a specific thread?

Following is the case where I call reloadData. Note: This is happening in another class when basicFactsViewController's viewWillAppear method has not been called yet:

```
- (BOOL) isComplete {
dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
    [basicFactsViewController.tableView reloadData];
});

return basicFactsViewController.isComplete && selectedVehicleId && selectedMakeId && selectedModelId && selectedYearId && selectedTrimId;
}
```

Now basicFactsViewController.isComplete is checked in this method:

```
- (BOOL) isComplete {
[self collectKeyHighlights];
return _isComplete;
}
```

Now the dictionary "tableCells" in the method below uses the cells population to check whether all features have been completed or not:

```
- (NSDictionary *) collectKeyHighlights {
NSMutableDictionary *key_highlights_update = [NSMutableDictionary new];
NSMutableDictionary *cell_highlight_update = [NSMutableDictionary new];
if(visible_key_highlights.count == 0) _isComplete = YES;
_isComplete = YES;
__block NSMutableArray *reloadCellAtIndexPathSet = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
[visible_key_highlights enumerateObjectsUsingBlock:^(id obj, NSUInteger idx, BOOL *stop) {
    NSDictionary *feature = (NSDictionary *)obj;
    UITableViewCell *cell = [self.tableCells objectForKey:[NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:idx inSection:0]];
    if(cell) {
        if([cell isKindOfClass:[DRColorSelectionTableViewCell class]]) {
            NSInteger selectedIndex = ((DRColorSelectionTableViewCell *)cell).selectedIndex;
            NSInteger numberOfSegments = ((DRColorSelectionTableViewCell *)cell).numberOfSegments;
            if(selectedIndex > -1 ) {
                NSArray *dataValues = [[visible_key_highlights objectAtIndex:idx] objectForKey:@"data_values"];
                NSDictionary *colorData;
                BOOL reloadCellForIndexPath = NO;
                if (numberOfSegments == selectedIndex) {
                    colorData = @{ @"normalized" : @"user_defined", @"isother" : @YES, @"hexcode":@"#FFFFFF", @"actual":((DRColorSelectionTableViewCell *)cell).otherColorTextField.text};
                    reloadCellForIndexPath = YES;
                }
                else{
                    colorData = [dataValues objectAtIndex:selectedIndex];
                }
                [key_highlights_update setObject:colorData forKey:[feature objectForKey:@"name"]];
                [cell_highlight_update setObject:colorData forKey:[feature objectForKey:@"name"]];
                if (![colorData isEqual:[prevSelections objectForKey:[feature objectForKey:@"name"]]]) {
                    [reloadCellAtIndexPathSet addObject:((DRColorSelectionTableViewCell *)cell).indexPath];
                }
                //if (reloadCellForIndexPath) {

                //}
            } else {
                _isComplete = NO;
            }
        } else if([cell isKindOfClass:[DRInputTableViewCell class]]) {
            NSString *textInput = ((DRInputTableViewCell *)cell).inputTextField.text;
            if([textInput length]) {
                [key_highlights_update setObject:[NSString toSnakeCase:textInput]  forKey:[feature objectForKey:@"name"]];
                [cell_highlight_update setObject:textInput forKey:[feature objectForKey:@"name"]];
            }else {
                _isComplete = NO;
            }
        } else if([cell isKindOfClass:[DRPickerTableViewCell class]]) {
            NSString *textInput = ((DRPickerTableViewCell *)cell).inputField.text;
            if([textInput length]) {
                [key_highlights_update setObject:[NSString toSnakeCase:textInput]   forKey:[feature objectForKey:@"name"]];
                [cell_highlight_update setObject:textInput forKey:[feature objectForKey:@"name"]];
            } else {
                _isComplete = NO;
            }
        } else if([cell isKindOfClass:[DRSwitchTableViewCell class]]) {
            // send this everytime for now
            BOOL isSelected = ((DRSwitchTableViewCell *)cell).toggleButton.selected;
            [key_highlights_update setObject:[NSNumber numberWithBool:isSelected] forKey:[feature objectForKey:@"name"]];
            [cell_highlight_update setObject:[NSNumber numberWithBool:isSelected] forKey:[feature objectForKey:@"name"]];
        }
    }
    else{
        _isComplete = NO;
    }
}];
prevSelections = cell_highlight_update;
if ([reloadCellAtIndexPathSet count]) {
    [self.tableView beginUpdates];
    [self.tableView reloadRowsAtIndexPaths:reloadCellAtIndexPathSet withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationNone];
    [self.tableView endUpdates];
}
return key_highlights_update;
}
```

Now here since 
    [tableView reloadData]

is not calling **cellForRowAtIndePath**:, hence, **tableCells** is not getting populated, hence, I am always getting _isComplete = NO.

Comment: Your `UITableViewDataSource` methods will only be called after you have called `reloadData`. It sounds like you want them to be called before `reloadData` in order to determine whether or not you should `reloadData`; this makes no sense. If you have a different question, please reword it to make your intention clear.

Comment: I'd need more details. What are you trying to do? Load the table before the view is loaded? Can you show some code and more explanation of what's dependent on the dataSource methods (and why)?

Comment: No, I would definitely not like to call datasource methods before reloadData is called. That's pointless. My point is that I am keeping a stack of cells in a dictionary which is populated in the cellForRowAtIndexPath method. Now, when I try to call reloadData from a reference of UIViewController class  in another class, it doesn't call the dataSource methods! Hence, I don't get this dictionary populated. On the basis of this dictionary I am checking whether the user has completed a task or not before and hence displaying a check icon in the previous ViewController.

Comment: I shall moreover edit my question with some code.

Comment: @skagzilla .. I have edited my question. Hope you understand what I am trying to achieve here.

Comment: @IanMacDonald Please see my edited code! I am burning my head over this since long...

Comment: You should manage your data state **outside** of your view.

Comment: @IanMacDonald ... Sorry I don't understand. Please elaborate.

Comment: You are attempting to affect your UI based on the state of a UI element in another view controller. Instead, you should be changing your UI based on a data change. When a user completes a task, save that state to a data model somewhere. When you are reloading your table to display check icons, read the state of your model. Determining the state of your data from the state of your UI is poor practice; don't do it unless absolutely necessary (hint: it's never absolutely necessary).

Comment: If you write the dataSource code, you can rig it so you can call the methods from anywhere.  Even if you don't write it, of the major methods only `cellForRow...` is especially sensitive to it's operating environment (beyond sensitivities based on the dataSource itself).  What happens if you call `cellForRow...` and it asks the TableView for a cell, when the TableView has not yet been displayed, I can't say.

Comment: "Now, when I try to call reloadData from a reference of UIViewController class in another class, it doesn't call the dataSource methods! Hence, I don't get this dictionary populated."  That makes it sound like you're depending on the TableView calling `cellForRow...` to populate your "dictionary".  That's a bad idea from several aspects, not the least that cells that are never scrolled into the visible range will not make it into you dictionary.  If you have a data structure that needs to be referenced from elsewhere, it should be developed directly from the dataSource structures.

Comment: Just because the approach is wrong doesn't mean that the question should be invalidated with a downvote! Atleast it will save others from using this kind of strategy.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly, there is processing being done when the tableview loads (calls it's dataSource methods) and you want to trigger that early to use its results. Calling `[basicFactsViewController.tableView reloadData];` early won't work if the basicFactsViewController hasn't been displayed yet. If basicFactsViewController is a UIViewController and has the default view and the tableView property is a subview of that standard view, then (if I remember correctly) the tableView property will be nil until the basicFactsViewController has been displayed. A shortcut around that is to access the viewController's view property and cause it to initialize (viewDidLoad and all that). You can do that by simply messaging the viewController: `[basicFactsViewController view]`.

If I've been right so far I'm fairly confident that will initialize the tableView property. But I'm not sure if it will cause the table view to load its data. And even if it does work, it's definitely not the best solution to the piece of code you're trying to architect. Apple's design for UIKit has been focused on the model/view/controller pattern and it's easier to go with the flow and do the same. I imagine that you could move the processing that is in the data source methods for the tableView out into another class (or maybe even the same class), and call that method to get everything ready for both the tableView and any other checks that you have, storing the data in dictionaries and arrays in such a way that you can easily load them by index into the tableView when cellForIndex is called.